# Downloading software pacakges frequently restarts

Tags: networking

When loading software packages e.g. with Synaptic Package Manager under 10.04LTS, for some files the progress bar jumps back to the left and starts again. This repeats many times or even forever.
Generating network traffic by accessing some website seems to help. So I end up hitting the reload button of the browser each time a download gets stuck.
Same behaviour was seen with the update manager and also right now, while doing a distribution upgrade from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS. Here the progress bar jitters a little bit and System Monitor shows a data rate that exceeds what my DSL connection is capable of.
Internet connection is done through a commercial firewall device.

Is such a behaviour normal, depending on a slow server?
If not, how can I diagnose this problem?

Comment: I still have a few boxes with 10.04. you might be facing retired repos, or something else, like power issues, perhaps your network card is trying to conserve power? what software are you trying to get? I think the first increments in the progress bar are attempting to contact the repo. https://launchpad.net/~lucid-bleed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa many other thins require install from source, and signifigant fiddling. link is for a repo I like.

Comment: 10.04 is beyond end of life on the desktop and will be at end of life on the server side at the end of the month. Synatpic is part of the ""desktop". I suggest you update with to a supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: The problem is independent of 10.04. I've meanwhile upgraded to 12.04 as an intermediate step and I'm now upgrading to 14.04.

Comment: ... The 'Distribution Upgrade' window lists 'Fetching file x of 2464', the progress bar slowly moves top the right, but eventually it jumps back to the left. Sometimes unrealistic data rates of PB/s are displayed. Reloading a web page in Firefox during that time seems to restore normal operation. As I could download large files via Firefox without problems, it must be some combination of software update and some networking problems. Is there a specific connection timeout for software updates?

Answer (score 0):

No, what you're seeing is an artefact of variable connection speed: Ubuntu does a calculation of the ETA depending on the speed of the connection.  If the speed drops significantly (for a variety of reasons) it will "jump back to the left" and when the speed normalises again, it will "jump back to the right".

You should contact your ISP and have them monitor your line to see whether this is "normal" or not...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the connection to the repositories and the calculated estimate time for package. Probably the connection to your current repository mirror is not good enough. You can use Synaptic to setup the fastest server for updates:

1. Launch Synaptic from the MintMenu (i.e. search for "synaptic" and run it).
2. From the Synaptic menu select Settings -> Repositories.
3. Select the Software tab in the Download From drop down, choose Other…
4. Click the Select Best Server button in the resulting dialog and wait a minute or perhaps more on a slow connection.
5. Once it’s finished select your server and click on Choose Server. close everything and click Reload in the main Synaptic window.
6. Close everything and click Reload in the main Synaptic window.
7. You should see Synaptic downloading package information in progress from your new mirror.